# SQL select unsubscribes from two separate lists

Tags: query, list, automation, sql

I am trying to write a SQl Query to Select unsubscribes from two lists over the last 7 days and place them into a Data Extension. The code below works for a single list, but I can't figure out how to get the second list included.

```
SELECT [EmailAddress], [Status]

FROM 
_ListSubscribers

WHERE
ListID = ######

AND
Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND
DateUnsubscribed > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

I tried running the two SQL Querys in an automation but it fails with with this as the error message:

> Query failed during execution. Error: Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint. Cannot insert duplicate key.

UPDATE: Got it to work with the following...

```
SELECT EmailAddress, Status, DateUnsubscribed
FROM _ListSubscribers
WHERE (ListID = 5132912 OR ListID = 5132362)
AND Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND DateUnsubscribed > DATEADD(d,-7,GETDATE())
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT [EmailAddress], [Status]

FROM 
_ListSubscribers

WHERE
ListID = ######

AND
Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND
DateUnsubscribed > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())

/*------------------------------------
ADD IN THIS UNION FOR THE SECOND LIST
--------------------------*/
UNION 

SELECT [EmailAddress], [Status]

FROM 
_ListSubscribers2  -- THIS IS THE SECOND LIST NAME

WHERE
ListID = ######

AND
Status = 'Unsubscribed'
AND
DateUnsubscribed > DATEADD(day, -7, GETDATE())
```

Comment: I didn't vote this answer down, but your posted content will be better received if you include an explanation rather than just a code dump.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not the one who voted you down. But consider adding some explanatory text and I would be happy to vote positively. As it stands the question does need some improvement. For instance, is the `UNION` syntax documented somewhere?